# How to get access to Armature pose bones info from Geometry nodes?

Tags: armature, geometry-nodes

I have an armature with several bones, each of them I would like to use to control transforms of other objects. Normally I would either directly parent objects to the bones or use constraints or drivers or something, but I wonder if it is possible to do it with Geometry nodes. It would be handy for me in order to keep the whole system consistent and organized. Could not find any node giving an access to the pose bones info. Is there such an option in the Geometry nodes?